# Alternate of sys_refcursor

Tags: sql, oracle, mule, oracle12c, tibco

What is the alternate of sys_refcursor.

After 12c upgrade, the resultset of `sys_refcursor` is unrecognizable by `mulesoft/tibco`. Reading it as `null`

Comment: Why? And What is your actual problem please?

Comment: After 12c upgrade, the resultset of sys_refcursor is unrecognizable by mulesoft/tibco. Reading it as null

Comment: @rajan.sngh Then why did you tag `11g` when you have upgraded to `12c`?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
TYPE cursor_type IS REF CURSOR;
```

or a strongly typed cursor:

```
CREATE PACKAGE SCHEMA_NAME.PACKAGE_NAME
AS
  TYPE Table_Name_Cursor IS REF CURSOR RETURN SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME%ROWTYPE;

  -- You said this does not work.
  -- PROCEDURE get_Weakly_Typed_Cursor (
  --   out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  -- );

  PROCEDURE get_Strongly_Typed_Cursor (
    out_cursor OUT Table_Name_Cursor
  );
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY SCHEMA_NAME.PACKAGE_NAME
AS
  PROCEDURE get_Strongly_Typed_Cursor (
    out_cursor OUT Table_Name_Cursor
  )
  AS
  BEGIN
    OPEN out_cursor FOR
    SELECT * FROM SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME;
  END;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own ref cursor type:

```
TYPE my_ref_cursor_type is REF CURSOR;
v_cursor my_ref_cursor_type;
```

But it would only make sense to do that if using a very old version of Oracle that didn't have SYS_REFCURSOR!